# Visual Studio for Windows (2022) - Cross compiling for Raspberry PI using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, raspberry-pi, windows-10, visual-studio-2022

I am in the process of rewriting a python program that utilizes OpenCV to do facial recognition and activate servo motors on a Pi 3/4.  This was started from the sample Raspberry PI Project (A blinking LED app). I am able to cross-compile my core code (separate classes/modules including threading) and debug/create the release for the Pi (from the Windows PC).  I am now ready to start adding in the OpenCV camera capture and recognition components but have not been able to find anything online on how to include the ARM headers/etc to pull this into the VS for Windows project for compiling.

I see many references to Visual Studio for the Pi but not compiling/debugging from Windows (over SSH).  Is this possible or am I making this harder than it needs to be?  I use Windows for my desktop/travel laptop.  This is a personal project so I am using the free version of VS Studio for Windows and would like to avoid spending $$ if at all possible.

Any assistance/direction on what I should be searching for/links to how to accomplish this would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes. you can used SSH from laptop.

Comment: I've Cross-compiled and debugged on Windows for the Pi using Eclipse successfuly in the past. 
For Eclipse, I used this tutorial to get started: https://www.cososo.co.uk/2015/12/cross-development-using-eclipse-and-gcc-for-the-rpi/.
For Visual Studio you can try VisualGDP : https://visualgdb.com/tutorials/raspberry/crosscompiler/ and https://visualgdb.com/tutorials/raspberry/ on a 30 day trial (sorry it's a commercial product). 
For Visual Code take a look at https://github.com/gloveboxes/Raspberry-Pi-with-Visual-Studio-Code-Remote-SSH-and-C-or-C-Development (not tried)